# Executing razor code within javascript function in .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to make a slide show. I am sending images as `Byte[]` I will convert it and assign it to an `<img>`'s SRC attribute. The `<img>`'s ID is `Gallery`

If you look at the following code I am sending more than one `Byte[]`. I need to display them at equal intervals.

To achieve this I am placing the `Razor` code within a `Javascript` function and trying to call the function at equal intervals. But no use, the function is not getting called.

Please help me out. Thanks

```
<script>
@{ 
  int increment = 0; 
  <text> 
  var step = 0; 
  function slideit() 
  { 
    @{ViewBag.photogallery = (List<IntranetSystem.Models.Gallery>)Session["Photo"]; 
    var base642 = Convert.ToBase64String(ViewBag.photogallery[increment].GalleryPhoto); 
    var imgSrc2 = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base642); 
    increment += 1;
    if (increment == ViewBag.photogallery.Count){ 
      increment = 0; 
     } 
    } 
  $("Gallery").attr('src', @imgSrc2); 
  } 
  </text> 
  setInterval("slideit()", 1000) 
 } 
</script>
```

Comment: When you read the source of the page on the browser have you a correct javascript code?

Comment: yes I can view the code

Comment: Post the code for the setInterval method as this is actually what triggers your function

Comment: `setInterval("slideit()", 1000)` is this what you are talking about? @heymega

Comment: @randomUser - Yeah is this a js function because its actually in your razor code block so it will be treat as C# code? You should move it outside the last }